# LALR(1) and SLR(1) parser

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, regex-lookarounds

I get a hypothesis from our teacher and he want from us to search and validate it. We have SLR(1) and LALR(1) parser. The hypothesis is:

> Suppose we have a language structure called X. If We couldn't provide a LALR(1) grammar for this structure, we couldn't provide a SLR(1) too and maybe a LR(1) grammar could solve problem. but If we could provide a LALR(1) grammar for this structure, we could provide a SLR(1) too.

If you search in internet, you find a lot of sites which say this grammar is not SLR(1) but it is LALR(1):

```
S -> R
S -> L = R
L -> * R
L -> id
R -> L
```

("id", "*" and "=" are terminals and others are non-terminals)
If we try to find SLR(1) items, we will see shift/reduce conflict. it is true, but my hypothesis say something else. In our hypothesis, we talk about **language** described by grammar not grammar itself! We can remove "R" and convert grammar to LL(1) and It is also SLR(1) and LALR(1):

```
S -> LM
M -> epsilon
M -> = L
L -> * L
L -> id
```

You can try this grammar and you can see that this grammar describe **same language** as last grammar and has SLR(1) and LALR(1) grammar!

so my problem is not finding a grammar which is LALR(1) but not SLR(1). There are a lot of them in internet. I want to know is there any **language** which has LALR(1) grammar but not SLR(1) grammar? and if our hypothesis is true, then there is no need to LALR(1) and SLR(1) could do everything for us, however LALR(1) is easier to use and maybbe in future, a **language** reject this hypothesis.

I'm sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Comment: This might be a better fit for cs.stackexchange.com but check [on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: I'm sorry. I see lots of question asked about SLR(1) and LALR(1) in stackoverflow. I think that I should ask it here. If I have to move, How can I move it?

Comment: Not a problem. It's not exactly off-topic here, I don't think, but you're going to get much better answers over there since SO is primarily programming folks with only some crossover to theoretical CS. I don't know how to migrate, so probably just delete and re-post by hand.

Comment: If migrated to [cs.se] (where it belongs), the question will be closed as a duplicate. See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43/language-theoretic-comparison-of-ll-and-lr-grammars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every LR(*k*) language has an SLR(1) grammar.

There is a proof in [this paper from 1976](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255672858_Transforming_LR_k_Grammars_to_LR1_SLR1_and_11_Bounded_Right-Context_Grammars), which provides an algorithm for constructing the SLR(1) grammar, if you have an LR(*k*) grammar *and know the value of **k***. Unfortunately, there is no algorithm which can tell you definitely whether a CFG is LR(*k*), much less provide the value of *k*. (If you somehow know that the grammar is LR(*k*), you can try successive values of *k* until you find one which works. But that procedure will never terminate if the grammar is not LR(*k*).)

The above comes from [this reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43/language-theoretic-comparison-of-ll-and-lr-grammars) on the [Computing Science StackExchange site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), which is a better place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

LR(1) > LALR(1) > SLR(1)

LR(1) is the most powerful, LALR(1) in less powerful and SLR(1) is least powerful. 
This is fact, because of the way the lookahead sets are computed.  (1) means lookahead of one token.  Here is a grammar that is LR(1), but not LALR(1) and definitely not SLR(1):

```
   G : S... <eof>
     ;
   S : c A1 t ';'
     | c A2 n ';'                       
     | r A2 t ';'
     | r A1 n ';'
     ;
  A1 : a 
     ;
  A2 : a 
     ;
```

This grammar cannot be made LALR(1) or SLR(1).  Or sure you can remove A1 and A2 and 
replace them with a, but then you have a different grammar.  The problem is that an
action may be attached to the rule A1 : a and a different action my be attached to A2 : a.   For example:

```
  A1 : a    => X()
     ;
  A2 : a    => Y()
     ;
```

An SLR(1) parser generator will report conflicts in your grammar that are not real conflicts.  I'm talking about the real world using large grammars (e.g. C11.grm).

The SLR(1) lookahead computation is simplistic, getting the lookaheads from the grammar, instead of the LR(0) state machine created by an LALR(1) parser  generator.

That is why Frank DeRemer's paper, in 1969, on LALR(1) is so important.

By looking at the grammar, A1 can be followed by either t or n, so this is a conflict
reported by SLR(1), but there is an LR(1) state machine in which there is no conflict on which follows A1.